# Query which performs like and in operators

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to run a Athena query which will match multiple values for a column. So the query is like this. So here the event name will be  'n' number of events in string with comma seperated.

```
eventname = "ExecuteQuery, ErrorOccured, RunningStatus, AbortStatus"

SELECT * FROM "db_name"."table_name" where account='123456' and  year='2010' and month='04' and day = '1'
and (eventname like  '%Execute%' or eventname like'%Error%' or eventname like '%Running%' or eventname like '%...%')
```

So basically I want query  to perform LIKE and IN operator

How can I write the sql query with  operator which has n number of events.
I tried with 'IN' operator. But didnt get desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM "db_name"."table_name" where account='123456' and  year='2010' and month='04' and day = '1'
and (eventname in  ('Execute%', '%Error%', 'Running%')
```

Also tried with below query and it throws error as **Function any not registered**

```
SELECT * FROM "db_name"."table_name" where account='123456' and and year='2020' and month='04' and day = '1'
and eventname LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%Execute%', 'Error%']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`regexp_like`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like), for example

```
select * from table where regexp_like(eventname, 'Execute|Error|Running' )
```